# can not convert json to struct object

Tags: swift

I want to parse JSON data into a struct object but i can't do it.
Actually the code is in different files but here i'm posting it as a whole.

Here is my code :

```
import Foundation

struct dataResponse: Decodable {
    var results: [userData]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var results = [userData] ()
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            if let route = try? container.decode(userData.self) {
                results.append(route)
            }
            else {
               _ = try? container.decode(dummyData.self)
            }
        }
        self.results = results
    }
}

private struct dummyData: Decodable { }

enum dataError: Error {
    case dataUnavailable
    case cannotProcessData
}

struct userData: Codable {
    var avatar: String
    var city: String
    var contribution: Int
    var country: String
    var friendOfCount: Int
    var handle: String
    var lastOnlineTimeSeconds: Int
    var maxRank: String
    var maxRating: Int
    var organization: String
    var rank: String
    var rating: Int
    var registrationTimeSeconds: Int
    var titlePhoto: String
}

struct dataRequest {
    let requestUrl: URL

    init(){
        self.requestUrl = URL(string: "https://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=abhijeet_ar")!
    }
    func getData(completionHandler: @escaping(Result<[userData], dataError>) -> Void) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.requestUrl) { (data,response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                completionHandler(.failure(.dataUnavailable))
                print("-------bye-bye--------")
                return
            }
            do {
                print("-------entered--------")
//                let dataresponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([userData].self, from: data)
//                print(type(of: dataresponse))
//               completionHandler(.success(dataresponse))
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                print(jsonResult)
                completionHandler(.success(jsonResult as! [userData]))
            }
            catch {
                completionHandler(.failure(.cannotProcessData))
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

here userData is my struct
the error says : Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x7fff8fe2dab0) to 'NSArray' (0x7fff8fe2dd30).

[image: JSON data from the server]

I would appreciate if anyone helps, thanks.

Comment: can you show your model of userData

Comment: The API response is a dictionary and you can't cast it to an array, for convert you should cast it to the dictionary and then use `result` key to access your array. Another way is using `codable` to convert your data  to your object that conform to codable protocol

Comment: And don’t hide the error in your catch

Comment: Maybe if you posted the response json structure I could include that too for you in my answer.

Comment: Add the json you are getting from server in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a very common mistake.

You are ignoring the root object which is a dictionary and causes the error.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let status : String
    let result: [UserData]
}

struct UserData: Decodable {
    let avatar: String
    let city: String
    let contribution: Int
    let country: String
    let friendOfCount: Int
    let handle: String
    let lastOnlineTimeSeconds: Int
    let maxRank: String
    let maxRating: Int
    let organization: String
    let rank: String
    let rating: Int
    let registrationTimeSeconds: Int
    let titlePhoto: String
}
```

Forget `JSONSerialization` and use only `JSONDecoder`

And it's not a good idea to return meaningless enumerated errors. Use `Error` and return the **real** error.

You get the array with `dataresponse.result`

```
struct DataRequest { // name structs always with starting capital letter
    let requestUrl: URL

    init(){
        self.requestUrl = URL(string: "https://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=abhijeet_ar")!
    }
    func getData(completionHandler: @escaping(Result<Root, Error>) -> Void) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.requestUrl) { (data,response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                completionHandler(.failure(error!))
                print("-------bye-bye--------")
                return
            }
            do {
                print("-------entered--------")
                let dataresponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                completionHandler(.success(dataresponse))   
            }
            catch {
                completionHandler(.failure(error))
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

And consider that if `status` is not "OK" the JSON response could be different.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are using the wrong struct. Create and use a `Response` struct for decoding. You need to keep your Types to have the first letter in capital to avoid confusion. You could use the `JSONDecoder()` maybe you are using something that doesn't have the correct format. Try the below code.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var result: [UserData]
}

enum DataError: Error {
    case dataUnavailable, cannotProcessData
}

struct DataRequest {

    let requestUrl: URL

    init(){
        self.requestUrl = URL(string: "https://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=abhijeet_ar")!
    }

    func getData(completionHandler: @escaping(Result<Response, DataError>) -> Void) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.requestUrl) { (data,response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                completionHandler(.failure(.dataUnavailable))
                return
            }
            do {
                let dataresponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
               completionHandler(.success(dataresponse))
            } catch {
                completionHandler(.failure(.cannotProcessData))
            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Note: Parameters in `UserData` always needs to right. Try with and Empty struct to check if everything else is working then proceed to adding the variable one-by-one.

Comment: yeah, i tried. it gives the error output : cannotProcessData

Comment: It means your `UserData` is not correct. Add the json you are getting from server to your question.